# Derived Class of Abstract Base Class does not correctly override Base pure virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

So I am trying to create a derived class of an Abstract Base class, but the pure virtual methods cannot be declared using the Derived class.

```cpp
template<class T>
class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual Foo<T>* add(const Foo<T>* rhs) = 0; 
};

template<class T>
class Doo : public Foo<T>
{
    public:
        Doo<T>* add(const Doo<T>* rhs)
        {
            return this;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Doo<double> d;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the add method declaration in `Doo` to work because `Doo` is a subclass of `Foo`, but g++ says that I am not overriding `Foo's` add method. I am assuming that this something simple with how I am declaring `Doo's` add method.

Comment: one takes a `Foo` the other a `Doo`, those are different methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signatures don't match so you don't override anything. Look up the `override` keyword to get your compiler to help you diagnose errors like this.

```
add(const Foo<T>* rhs)
```

is not the same as

```
add(const Doo<T>* rhs)
```

They take different arguments.

They also return different types. But return types do not matter in overload resolution or when overriding, but it's usually also a sign that you are missing the mark (of what you want to override), since *usually* you want your overriding function to return the same type as what it overrides.

Comment: I saw that would solve the problem, but my concern is that any other class derived from Foo could be passed into this method. Is the only resolution to make sure that inherited objects don't violate parent requirements?

Comment: @evader110 Sorry, not quite clear to me what you are asking there.

Comment: If I made another derived class called ```Goo``` derived from ```Foo``` would it work if I passed it into Doo's add method? If so, would creating a nonvirtual method within Doo be the only way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @evader110 By declaring a pure virtual `add` method, `Foo` promises that all derived classes will have an `add` method that accepts a pointer to `Foo`.  An `add` method that places any additional restrictions on its parameter does not fulfill that promise, and therefore is not considered an implementation of that pure virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

By using a function with different signature you have hidden the function instead of overriding it.

The best way to guard yourself against those errors is to use `override` keyword as following (in your example) every time you intend to override a virtual function:

```
Doo<T>* add(const Doo<T>* rhs) override
```

And than compiler will issue an error if the function does not actually override.